# Python 3 equivalent of Python 2 str.decode('hex')

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, decode

I'm trying to convert IEEE 754 floats in hex to standard python floats.

The following works in Python 2.x :

```
foo ='4074145c00000005'
conv_pound = struct.unpack('!d', foo.decode('hex'))[0]
print(conv_pound)
```

and produces the following output (which is indeed the number that I want):

```
321.272460938
```

However, python 3 does not have a str.decode method and I'm struggling to find how to do this. Any tips ?

Comment: I've tried that but unless I'm missing something I'm getting @t\x14\\\x00\x00\x00\x05' as the result

Comment: Definitely *not* a duplicate because the methods showed in "duplicate" will give a string and not a bytes object. In this case as the answer belows shows, we have to stop halfway.

Comment: @kriss Well, the OP already had the other half, they just had to put 2 and 2 together.  Definitely a dupe.

Comment: @Wim: definitely not a dupe that's like pretending bytes type is a duplicate of str type in python. Wreacks havoc! Of course some people can get the answer by themselves and don't need SO.

Comment: Also it's exactly why I voted to reopen: the current answer gives the fast answer but does not explains the difference between bytes and str in python 3, which could be useful to future readers. And ok, another way would be to add an answer to the "duplicate" to explain the difference.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.fromhex

Answer (score 9):

[`bytes.fromhex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) worked for me in python3:

```
Python 3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> foo ='4074145c00000005'
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('!d', bytes.fromhex(foo))
(321.2724609375003,)
>>> struct.unpack('!d', bytes.fromhex(foo))[0]
321.2724609375003
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had the pieces but I struggled to put them together

Comment: @user3352975 you're welcome!

Comment: Doesn't work for all hex strings, though. For instance, `bytes.fromhex('82').decode('utf-8')` raises `UnicodeDecodeError`. Using `'ascii'` format doesn't fix the problem, since that will fail for bytes with values >127.